# Laravel filter based on related model properties

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, relational-database

i have two models users and tasks with many to many relation between them,
tasks have self nested relation with itself as parent and child,

now i want get users who are currently free i.e. No task is assigned or assigned tasks have status either completed or closed , below is the code i wrote and toSql of that ,
but i am still getting users with tasks with other status such as in-progress and under-review

```
$freeEmployees = User::where('role', 'employee')->where(function ($q) {
           $q->doesntHave('task')
             ->orWhereHas('task', function ($q1) {
               $q1->where('status', config('taskstatus.completed'))
                   ->orWhere('status', config('taskstatus.closed'));
           });
       })->get()->take($limit);
```

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `role` = 'employee' AND(
        NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `task_checklist`
        INNER JOIN `user_task` ON `task_checklist`.`id` = `user_task`.`task_id`
        WHERE
            `users`.`id` = `user_task`.`user_id` AND `task_checklist`.`archived_at` IS NULL
    ) OR EXISTS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `task_checklist`
    INNER JOIN `user_task` ON `task_checklist`.`id` = `user_task`.`task_id`
    WHERE
        `users`.`id` = `user_task`.`user_id` 
        AND(
            `status` = 'Completed' OR `status` = 'Closed') 
        AND `task_checklist`.`archived_at` IS NULL
)
    )
ORDER BY
    `updated_at`
DESC
```

Comment: Your laravel query and sql query doesnt match. Can you show us your database structure?

Comment: @RajuAhmed
table name for TASK is ''task_checklist'', also i am using global scope to hide any task with status of archived using field 'archived_at'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not do it in another way ....

get me the employees while they don't have uncompleted tasks ...

```
$freeEmployees = User::where('role', 'employee')->whereDoesntHave('tasks', function ($q) {
               $q1->where('status', config('taskstatus.running'))
                   ->orWhere('status', config('taskstatus.uncompleted'));
           });
       })->get()->take($limit);
```

Comment: thanks it worked , 
could you explain a bit why it didnt worked the way i was doing

Comment: $q1->where('status', config('taskstatus.completed'))
                   ->orWhere('status', config('taskstatus.closed'));
this where must be a one block not two, means it must be:
$q1->where(function($query){
$query->'status', config('taskstatus.completed'))
                   ->orWhere('status', config('taskstatus.closed'));
}